# Why jQuery validation plugin is not working on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, jquery-validate

jQuery validation is working locally, but it doesn't on Heroku.

There is no errors about it in console. What should I do ?

**EDITED**

```
      den@DENYS /D/myapp (master)
     $ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
     c:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe c:/Ruby192/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAIL
     uction RAILS_GROUPS=assets
     rake aborted!
     Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

     Tasks: TOP => environment
     (See full trace by running task with --trace)
     rake aborted!
     Command failed with status (1): [c:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe c:/Ruby192/bi

     Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
     (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you precompiled your assets before pushing to heroku?

```
  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

You can find more information [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar/).

If it doesn't solve your problem, please provide the `heroku logs` in your question.